# Spotify user albums mismatch

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, libspotify, spotify-app

While fetching User Library albums at this endopoint:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums
```

> See api reference [here](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/library/get-users-saved-albums/)

the api call returns a small part of album list. But in Spotify App or Spotify Desktop App, it shows a different number of albums.

Does anyone know how to get artists from the library as I can't find any API documentation for it?

Comment: can you please specify how different the results you're getting are?

Comment: @data_garden on the app/desktop app its showing 8(while selecting saved albums only) / 19(without selecting saved) albums but through that API getting 6 albums only.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in Spotify's [User Library endpoint](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/library/):

> METHOD, ENDPOINT, USAGE, **RETURNS**
>
> GET, /v1/me/albums,    Get Current User's Saved Albums,    **saved albums**

The above call will only return user 's *saved albums*.

So if you want to retrieve all albums depicted in your desktop via api calls, you must save all of them within the Desktop app, otherwise you'll have the discrepancy you describe in your question.